# How do I add content to my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a little JS function here: http://jsfiddle.net/9UzNq/7/
When you click the bar, it expands to 300px from it's height.
I tried applying a div for content in there, but couldn't figure it out.

```
var open = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#title').click(function () {
        open = !open;
        $('#ABCD').animate({
            height: open ? "300" : "0"
        }, 700);
        if (open) $('#title').addClass('glow');
        else $('#title').removeClass('glow');
    });
});
```

The content div should open at the same time with the 'wrapit'.

Answer (score 1):

You just put the parent div #ABCD height to 0px, but the child has already content in it, so it's still displayed.

Read again this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), especially the examples part. You can use toggle for example

```
$('#ABCD').animate({
    height: "toggle"
}, 700);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, Just empty/fill your content div's text during runtime and make use of the call back function of [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
var open = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#title').click(function () {
        open = !open;

         $('#ABCD').empty();

        $('#ABCD').animate({
            height: open ? "300" : "0"
        }, 700,function(){

            if (open){ $('#title').addClass('glow');
                     $('#ABCD').text("Some content that shouldn't be showed before the div 'ABCD' is open");
                     }
            else{ $('#title').removeClass('glow');  }

        });


    });
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9UzNq/8/)

Answer (score 0):

What i did was set the visibility of `#ABCD` to hidden.  When you click you title, use jQuery to set the visibility back to `visible`.

**css**

```
#ABCD {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    height: 0px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#title').click(function () {
        open = !open;
        $('#ABCD').animate({ height: open ? "300" : "0" }, 700);
        if (open){
            $('#title').addClass('glow');
            $('#ABCD').css('visibility','visible');
        }
        else{
            $('#title').removeClass('glow');
            $('#ABCD').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    });
});
```